# how to initialize aes encoder based on key length

Tags: rust, aes

When using the `aes` crate, trying to initialize different encoders according to the key length, I have to write some terrible code like this:

```rust
if (0..=16).contains(&key_len) {
    let dec_cipher = Aes128Dec::new(GenericArray::from_slice(key_bytes));
    dec_cipher.decrypt_padded_b2b_mut::<Pkcs7>(data_bytes, &mut encoded)?;
} else if key_len <= 24 {
    let dec_cipher = Aes192Dec::new(GenericArray::from_slice(key_bytes));
    dec_cipher.decrypt_padded_b2b_mut::<Pkcs7>(data_bytes, &mut encoded)?;
} else {
    let dec_cipher = Aes256Dec::new(GenericArray::from_slice(key_bytes));
    dec_cipher.decrypt_padded_b2b_mut::<Pkcs7>(data_bytes, &mut encoded)?;
}
```

as the `Aes128Dec`, the `Aes192Dec` and the `Aes256Dec` haven't implemented the same trait, which should have contained the encode interface `dec_cipher.decrypt_padded_b2b_mut::<Pkcs7>(data_bytes, &mut encoded)?;`. So is there any way to do this in a more elegant way, or a better interface to use?

I suppose this way is far better, but it's wrong as there is no trait for the encrypt function:

```rust
let dec_cipher = if (0..=16).contains(&key_len) {
    Aes128Dec::new(GenericArray::from_slice(key_bytes))
} else if key_len <= 24 {
    Aes192Dec::new(GenericArray::from_slice(key_bytes))
} else {
    Aes256Dec::new(GenericArray::from_slice(key_bytes))
}
dec_cipher.decrypt_padded_b2b_mut::<Pkcs7>(data_bytes, &mut encoded)?;
```

Comment: Your latter example is not only wrong because there is no common trait. It's wrong because it won't typecheck, because `dec_cipher` can only have one type among `Aes128Dec`, `Aes192Dec` and `Aes256Dec`. There are ways to encode an alternative among these three types, but they incur a runtime overhead, and are probably less straightforward than what you are already doing.

Comment: *"but it's wrong as there is no trait for the encrypt function"* - I'd challenge this. `AesXDec` structs do not **have** the `decrypt_padded_b2b_mut` function, it is provided by the [`BlockDecryptMut`](https://docs.rs/cipher/0.4.4/cipher/trait.BlockDecryptMut.html#method.decrypt_padded_b2b_mut) trait.

Comment: Correction of my previous statement: `BlockDecryptMut` is `: Sized` and therefore not object safe :/ Although I'm having a hard time understanding where the `: Sized` requirement comes from.